# JPA Query: select all parents that have their last child with a specific property

Tags: java, jpa, jpql

I'm guessing how the query below could be written through JPQL:

> Select all parents(side 1 of a 1-n relationship) which last child
>   (newest id) has a specific value for a column (attribute). My entities look like

Parent.java

```
@Entity
class Parent {

@Id
@Column(name="ID_PARENT")
@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY) 
private Long id;

@OneToMany(mappedBy="parent")
private List<Child> children;

}
```

Child.java

```
@Entity 
class Child {

@Id
@Column(name="ID_CHILD")
@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY) 
private Long id;


@ManyToOne()
@JoinColumn(name="ID_PARENT")
private Parent parent;

private String attribute;


}
```

What would JPQL look like?
Thank you all

Answer (score 0):

It should not be very different from a SQL. I got this working in a similar DB I have here.

```
SELECT *
FROM Parent p
INNER JOIN Child c
ON c.ID_PARENT   = p.ID_PARENT
WHERE c.ID_CHILD =
  (SELECT c2.ID_CHILD
  FROM Child c2
  WHERE c.ID_PARENT = c2.ID_PARENT
  AND c2.attribute = <parameter>
  AND c2.ID_CHILD   =
    (SELECT MAX(c3.ID_CHILD)
    FROM apuracao_fator_risco c3
    WHERE c2.ID_PARENT = c3.ID_PARENT
    )
  )
```

These posts can also be useful:

[JPA Select latest instance for each item](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6296347/jpa-select-latest-instance-for-each-item)

[JPA sorting query by property of last element in child collection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15575694/jpa-sorting-query-by-property-of-last-element-in-child-collection)

Comment: Thank you, Vitor. But the problem is exactly translating it to jpql. I pretended to do something like that, but couldn't get how to do so with jpa, without native queries.